# Laptop as second monitor for PC

Tags: ati, multiple-monitors

I haven't found any solutions for my particular problem yet.

My PC got Windows 7 and my ASUS F552E has ubuntu 14.04.

I connected the laptop with my graphicscard on my pc to use the laptop as an second monitor . To switch screens I have to press on FN+F8. The outcome is a black screen.
The video card driver for my laptop is installed correctly and the pc is dected on my laptop.
I also can't change the screen in the display nor in the amd catalyst center options.

So, have I overseen something? Maybe someone had the same problem and got some solutions.

Greetings,
Daniel

Comment: So, do you want to use your screen from the laptop to your PC? To see on your screen from the laptop what you see on your monitor from your PC?

Comment: Basically yes. I want to extend (not clone) the desktop of my PC to my laptop

Comment: Well, your PC has Windows 7, not Ubuntu, so your question is [off-topic](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) here and it will be probably closed.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this. You can use your laptop as a remote display client to your PC, but you cannot simply *extend* the display output from one computer to another.

Comment: Well thanks, had that in thought but was not sure